# Cannot rotate ground overlay in React Google Maps - property "bearing " is ignored

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I am using the lib React Google Maps to display a map. I need to place a image with fixed bounds but it has a rotation, because its like a blueprint of a building. To achieve this, I am using GroundOverlay. My problem is, when I set a property option with bearing property, this property is ignored. It does not rotate.

This is where I found bearing property.
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlayOptions#bearing(float)

This is the lib docs:
https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#groundoverlay

Here is my code:

```
<LoadScript googleMapsApiKey="API-KEY">
        <GoogleMap mapContainerStyle={containerStyle} center={center} zoom={18}>
            <GroundOverlay
              key={"url"}
              url={planta}
              options={{ bearing: 30 }}
              bounds={{
                north,
                south,
                east,
                west,
              }}
            />
        </GoogleMap>
</LoadScript>
```

If anyone know how can I rotate that image, will be appreciated. I need a solution that could be dynamic and not for that specific image, cause the idea is to render it from backend with the property bearing.

HERE IS A LIVE EXAMPLE, I NEED TO ROTATE THIS IMAGE:
https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-jackson-ul6ws?file=/src/App.js

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [GroundOverlayOptions - bearing property](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlayOptions#bearing(float)) is for Android Maps SDK. While [GroundOverlay for Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/image-overlay#GroundOverlay) doesn't have bearing options.

I checked [react-google-maps library](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#overlayview), you can use [OverlayView](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#overlayview) instead.

To rotate the overlay, you can use the [CSS transform Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) to rotate your div. Here's a [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sample-overlay-view-react-google-maps-n33kbz?file=src/index.js) and a code snippet below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
const { compose, withProps, withStateHandlers } = require("recompose");
//const FaAnchor = require("react-icons/lib/fa/anchor");
const {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  OverlayView,
} = require("react-google-maps");

const getPixelPositionOffset = (width, height) => ({
  x: -(width / 2),
  y: -(height / 2),
})

const MapWithAnOverlayView = compose(
  withStateHandlers(() => ({
    count: 0,
  }), {
    onClick: ({ count }) => () => ({
      count: count + 1,
    })
  }),
 withProps({
    googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)(props =>
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={3}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}
  >
    <OverlayView
     bounds={{
         ne: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
          sw: { lat: -34.397, lng: 50.644 }
        }}
      //position={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}
      /*
       * An alternative to specifying position is specifying bounds.
       * bounds can either be an instance of google.maps.LatLngBounds
       * or an object in the following format:
       * bounds={{
       *    ne: { lat: 62.400471, lng: -150.005608 },
       *    sw: { lat: 62.281819, lng: -150.287132 }
       * }}
       */
      /*
       * 1. Specify the pane the OverlayView will be rendered to. For
       *    mouse interactivity, use `OverlayView.OVERLAY_MOUSE_TARGET`.
       *    Defaults to `OverlayView.OVERLAY_LAYER`.
       */
      mapPaneName={OverlayView.OVERLAY_MOUSE_TARGET}
      /*
       * 2. Tweak the OverlayView's pixel position. In this case, we're
       *    centering the content.
       */
      getPixelPositionOffset={getPixelPositionOffset}
      /*
       * 3. Create OverlayView content using standard React components.
       */
    >
      <div style={{ background: `white`, border: `1px solid #ccc`, padding: 15 , transform: 'rotate(80deg)' }}>
        <h1>OverlayView</h1>
        <img src="https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg" />
      </div>
    </OverlayView>
  </GoogleMap>
);



render(<MapWithAnOverlayView />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to implement your suggestion but I noticed that I´ve tried it before and the problem with overlay view is that when you zoom in and zoom out, it does not resizes the overlay... I need something that will stick its bounds somewhere in my map regardless of the zoom degree i am

Comment: I see. It looks like the div being created in the <OverlayView/> follows the html dimensions set on it and not the bounds in the map. If you are looking for an overlay that you can rotate that sticks on the bounds of the map regardless the zoom level, it is possible with the [Custom Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays) of Maps JavaScript API. Here is a [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/customoverlay-sample-map-c1twos?file=App.js) that implements this without any react libraries for google maps.Please put your API key in Map.js.